# Are there professional benefits to building reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I've been on Stack Overflow for quite some time and to be honest I used this site only to get answers to my technical queries. But I've seen many profiles of experts, and they have earned really really nice reputation by answering questions. So I'm just wondering if there are any direct professional benefits to me if I spend a lot of time and effort building my reputation on the site? Will it directly help me getting/switching job? After all, Stack Overflow is for professionals and enthusiasts.

In short, other than *getting pleasure from helping others*, are there any direct professional benefits of building reputation on Stack Overflow? Getting answers to these questions will help me decide how much effort I want to put into answering questions, and seriously building reputation.

Comment: take a look at https://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/9948/285 and its duplicate

Comment: I don't have enough experience to give an informed answer, but I *suspect* that for every hiring manager who thinks SO rep is great, there's another out there who worries about how a prima donna will fit in with the rest of the team.

Comment: @GayotFow are you trying to tell us that we're all a bunch of "prima donnas"? `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake, Heavens no!  But it would be a mistake to think that a six sigma SO rep is perceived by all hiring managers as a purely one-dimensional indicator.

Comment: Don't forget about http://careers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: (Note: User *"Cupcake"* is now user *"user456814"* (account deleted). There is also [a deleted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254257/are-there-professional-benefits-to-building-reputation/254261#254261) (referred to in [Makoto's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254257/are-there-professional-benefits-to-building-reputation#comment18496_254257)). Based on the information there, there may be a second account, user *"[Danny Dai Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2616601/danny-dai-smith)"*. Or a wrong link was used.)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I got my job at Google because of my Stack Overflow profile.

I was still in school when I started using SO. And towards the end of my last year in school, recruiters from several companies (including Google) contacted me. I picked a subset of those to follow through and interviewed with 4 of them. 3 gave me an offer and I chose Google.

2 of the 4 companies I interviewed with admitted that they found me through Stack Overflow.
(The Google recruiter actually found me through a Hacker News link to one of my answers on SO.)

Even now, I still get a lot of emails from recruiters. Almost all of them are through either LinkedIn or Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm curious, how much rep did you have when you started being recruited?

Comment: And was it before you posted the most upvoted answer on SO ever? :)

Comment: [I just checked](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A11770)...nope, it really ***is*** the highest scoring answer on [main], EVAR! `:P`

Comment: @connor This happened in October 2012. Looking at my [rep graph](http://stackexchange.com/users/559988/mysticial?tab=reputation), I had about 60k rep at the time.

Comment: @juergend Recruiters started contacting me long *before* I answered the Branch Prediction question. (As early as 2 months after I joined SO.) But most of the action happened during my final semester - which was *after* I posted that answer. So while that Branch question contributed, it definitely wasn't the only factor.

Comment: A guy with 60K reputation (at the time) deserves to be hired by the best. Google was fortunate to have landed Dr. Mystical. (Note: i worked at google for several years)

Comment: Can you link to the Hacker News link and that answer you mention they referenced?

Answer (score 17):

Besides attracting recruiters attention to you, as *Mysticial* wrote, I can point at one more important aspect of being here. I am here because using this site I can improve and deepen my knowledge in particular areas. Just one little example:

Once I answered a user that he or she could use Java `Collections.synchronizedXXX()`. I also wrote that mutex, used for that synchronization, is the collection's `this`. Another user commented on my post and pointed out that we can pass any object there, in order to be used as a mutex.

So, to sum up, here are the benefits I can name:

- Self-promotion. Good profiles attract attention, and the answer above has an example of a success story;
- Getting answers to your questions. Using bounty, most likely getting it **fast**;
- Improving the overall quality of the site, assuming you use it adequately;
- Improving your own knowledge. I consider this a little bit different than the second point and wrote the example above;

Comment: I definitely agree that even just ***answering questions*** can actually teach you things that you didn't already know before. Personally, I learned more about Git than I ever did before, just by doing research in order to answer other people's questions! `:D`

Comment: @Cupcake Yeah, exactly what I'm speaking about.

Comment: I use SO a fair amount in my everyday work, and like you and @Cupcake, I find answering questions useful to expand on my own knowledge. Moreover, I feel that I should contribute (where I can) to a site I find so useful, which is why I occasionally edit pages on Wikipedia (mostly typo corrections and linking to other articles, but contributions nonetheless).