# Would you consider Stack Overflow 'reputation' valuable at interviews?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Following on from *[Is it legitimate to "buy" Stack Overflow reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270795/is-it-legitimate-to-buy-stack-overflow-reputation/270815#270815)* prompted the question: Would you consider Stack Overflow reputation something relevant to the job application/interview process? (And similar assumption elsewhere on Stack Exchange where professionally relevant.)

It hadn't honestly occurred to me that people might care about such things.

Have you ever either been asked, or asked about such things as part of a job application process? And did it make a difference to the outcome?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270795/is-it-legitimate-to-buy-stack-overflow-reputation

Comment: It helps you get into the door and is worth a chunk of money on the offer.  The absolute worst thing is being exposed as a fraud for everybody to see, background checks on employees routinely use web searches these days to check for credibility.   Having a bad record somewhere will haunt you for many years.

Comment: Oh, I'm not suggesting being deceptive with it - merely whether 'being active' on Stack Overflow might count as 'Career development'.

Comment: I wouldn't consider reputation itself that valuable at an interview, but being able to see a sample of a candidate's code and how they interact with other developers definitely is.

Comment: There's an old question on programmers.SE (closed) that's worth reading (together with linked questions):

https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/107326/how-much-stack-overflow-reputation-makes-it-worth-putting-in-cv?lq=1

Comment: [Is Stack Overflow reputation marketable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30578/165773) / [Should I include information about my reputation on professionally-relevant Stack Exchange (or other Q&A) sites on my resume?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/308/168)

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong people. The people here are technically minded, know how Stack Overflow works and what reputation actually means. I don't think that makes them representative of the individuals (mainly HR and managers) that make hiring decisions.

Comment: Candidate: _"I got eleventy beeeellion Facebook likes for posting a Nyan cat video."_ Equally worthless.

Comment: Raw reputation score? No. Actual questions you've asked and answers you've given? Yeah. If the person looking has a technical background.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Hey, the ability to get a billion likes on a video might be a very useful skill.  Even as a programmer, being able to sell yourself and your work to others is highly valuable, and indicative of other skills.

Comment: @Joe: +1 for a level of sarcasm way above mine. Unless, of course, you were being serious ... Aren't internet 'Brownie Points' wonderful?

Comment: I find it is not the rep but the content of the account, the rep is meaningless

Comment: @Sammaye I disagree that rep is meaningless.  High rep can catch the eye of a recruiter, but as BilltheLizard and MattBurland state, it's the contents of the account that matter more.

Comment: I got several job offers that referred explicitly to my SO reputation and GH profile. So while it's not a strict indication it definitely opens doors. I dare say too many doors (to the point I've considered changing my alias to something that isn't my name).

Comment: @jmstoker I will conceed to that, even I might be moved by a higher rep, though I like to deny that I would :\

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Similarly for me. And although there has been no mention of rep, I have a feeling it has happened more often since I hit 100k or so. So yes, it can open doors, but I wouldn't put it in my CV or mention it in an interview.

Comment: I think it is more an indication of how much time a person is messing around on SO instead of working.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I got job offers from having 1k rep in MongoDB tag :\ it is odd how even though everyone on here wants to say rep is meaningless in the real world it doesn't seem to be

Comment: @Sammaye people like saying rep is meaningless in the real world because it makes it a lot less stressful - in practice it opens a lot of doors, a lot of room for networking and it makes a good impression. People will often deny it but it's definitely the truth. I remember answers I posted in SO where I got a job offer with a job relating to the answer within a week from posting the answer.

Comment: Recruiters generally don't care about your rep number. Either they know the game and they understand that rep can be gained without knowing anything. Or they don't know what the number means and thus don't consider it at all.

Comment: @Mysticial Yeah, I knew this one guy that earned like all his rep by posting [one answer with a couple of pretty pictures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902). :-p

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25760407/468718 after looking at this question I don't think reputation directly equals to hire this programmer because there lot of other factors too involved

Comment: It did **get** me the interview...

Comment: I was asked for my reputation once in an interview.  I told them I was over 3k and they said that was too high and I spent too much time on the site.  I think it depends a lot on the person

Comment: If I were interviewing someone I'd be rather suspicious if they bragged of a high SO rep. Even if you're not gaming the system, a higher than "normal" (for age/experience/et al) rep suggests that you spend too much time on SO and (very possibly) not enough elsewhere.

Comment: If you have a very high reputation on stackoverflow, you don't need a job. You live from your own knowledge and your projects.

Comment: see also: [Professional benefits of building reputation on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254257/professional-benefits-of-building-reputation-on-so)

Comment: @HotLicks by "elsewhere", do you mean server fault or meta?

Comment: @Mena - I mean among real people.

Comment: @HotLicks I was joking. But I'd argue SE sites' content is curated and moderated by real people (*mostly*).

Comment: @Mena - Dunno... I'd swear that they have a bot set up just to delete about half my comments.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree comment removal can be as annoying as repeated identification of traffic lights in a picture (and sometimes mused on how ironic it would be if the earlier was conditional to the latter). This said, I'd also argue that there isn't "too much time" spent on, e.g. SO if it somehow has something to do with your job. That is unless you work in a bunker and have an Office Space manager type staring at your screen and counting the lines of code you write by the minute all day long.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I would say that reputation *itself* doesn't matter much. However, high reputation on StackExchange does demonstrate participation in a large technical forum, and shows that you're providing good quality peer-reviewed answers.

The really beneficial part is that a prospective employer can take a look at some of your answers and get an idea for what areas you're strong in, how good you are at explaining things, and the quality of your technical writing.

As a concrete example, I've got about 45k rep over at Security SE, and wrote a rather nice layman's-terms explanation of SQL injection over there. At the interview for my current job, they commented that they quite liked that explanation and probed me on some of the finer points of it. It certainly wouldn't have been enough to score me the job on its own, but it was a nice talking point.

Comment: How did you get credit for this? (I notice you post under a pseudonym.) A link for your personal blog or social media, or a bolder link from your resume or cover letter?

Comment: @dcorking I mentioned my StackExchange profile in the "Community" area of my CV, as I'd won a community competition over there and it seemed relevant. That being said, it should be relatively trivial to find out who I am, and even more trivial to find this account from my real-name profiles elsewhere.

Answer (score 50):

I interview people for software development positions from time to time. (Not currently hiring so please don't ask.)

I've never asked for reputation on SO or anywhere else. I don't recall getting such numbers from applicants but it could be that I just don't remember. I could easily forget having seen such numbers because really **reputation on SO does not mean much when it comes to hiring for the kind of positions I hire for**.

Once a candidate has sent me a code sample that looks good, and once the candidate has passed an *extremely* simple coding test, **then, and only then,** would I take a look at some of the posts this user made on a site like SO. The reputation number in itself would not matter much. I'd look at the quality of the posts and the attitude that comes with them. I'd rather hire someone who has a generally good attitude.

Comment: I haven't interviewed people lately but if someone gave me their SO username, I wouldn't bother with the rep either, I'd just read a sample of their responses and comments. However if the rep was very high, I might start to be concerned whether or not this person spends a bit too much time on SO. :)

Comment: The other thing I'd look at is the tag list, as it would give me a rough overview of the applicant's other technical interests or skills that aren't necessarily part of the job as it stands but it may be useful to know that there's someone in a team who knows about them.

Comment: +1, first assess the applicant's real skills, THEN take a look at a shiny badge and number on a website (who knows if he bought his reputation or he's unable to code even an hello world without google..)

Answer (score 34):

> Have you ever either been asked, or asked about such things as part of a job application process? And did it make a difference to the outcome?

Yes.  My current job included a SQL proficiency test that was skipped for me based on my postings here (by some dumb fluke, I had actually answered a question from one of their DBAs asking about a Pivot report someone had created for them earlier).  They still went through the 'personality fit' and making sure I would enjoy the job that I'm in, but the technical portions were skipped because of my participation on Stack Overflow.

That was for my current full-time position.  Prior to that, I was jumping from contract to contract and one of the staffing companies that I used would direct people to Stack Overflow as 'proof' that their contractors (me included) knew their stuff well enough to tackle the 'complex' SQL questions they had (complex being quoted…complexity is relative I guess).

HR seems to like the term 'guru' (I hate it)—a person that could answer any question on that topic that they could possibly think of.  Stack Overflow can work as proof of this "hey I answer other developers questions all the time".  If the HR person (or anyone in the company) lacks the knowledge to properly evaluate someone else's knowledge, reputation on Stack Overflow can be used

Comment: I see very often these days a request/suggestion to share your SO profile and/or you GitHub *portfolio* in job postings.

Comment: Wait, what? You have (fairly) *low* stack overflow rep, and I have (fairly) *high* stack overflow rep, so I would venture to say that your example proves that rep is not important. Activity in topics relevant to the job, on the other hand, is important.

Comment: @SteveJessop All things relative.  For a user familiar with stack as a reference site, but hasn't actually tried answer, 2k+ seem relatively high.  Yes, it's by no means 100k+ (which I doubt a user under 5 years on stack could acquire anymore, it's exceedingly rare to see any current sql question/answer receive more then 5 upvotes), but it does display a capability to answer questions as well as the desire to be in the field.

Comment: @PM77-1  - It's a distinct change from a year or two ago when it was all about Linked-In profiles.

Answer (score 25):

So, people here seem to claim that rep is magical unicorn points - which is all nice but I think it's very far from reality in my own personal experience.

Rep in Stack Overflow is a measure of community participation and I wouldn't say there is a causal link between higher rep and being a good programmer. However, people who are hiring in the market seem to not be fully aware of that fact. Rep also means that the individual is interested in their field which is a big plus.

While I wouldn't ask about rep in an interview nor was I ever asked about rep directly in an interview (though I was asked about Stack Overflow) - here are some things a modestly high rep in Stack Overflow (and a GH profile) has gotten me. In all fairness I'm not looking for a job so I don't interview much. Had I been looking for a job these would make for some great opportunities:

- A bunch of job interviews at fairly big companies.
- An interview at a big search engine company who also makes a mobile OS.
- An interview at a big social networking company associated with the color blue.
- An invitation to come consult for a company abroad, paid with expenses covered.
- A whole bunch of interviews at startup companies.

So, is it in my opinion *relvant* - yes. Does it mean someone is a good programmer? No. Do HR usually know that? I'd also say no.

Comment: That is the problem: is that every CV must hit HR in a larger company before they hit IT, and rep does seem to cater to them. Some large companies will prevent this but the vast majority do not since their HR deals with so many industry areas it is impossible to train them for everything. I would personally state my rep and my top 10 answers/questions so I cater to both

Comment: Why not say the real names on the companies you are talking about? I doubt their lawyers would be knocking at your door the next morning. I don't see the point of making things cryptic.

Comment: @Victor in every case I get to choose between disclosing and not disclosing information where parties might or might not be interested in me sharing that information - I don't share it.

Comment: Obviously you are talking about Google and Facebook, so you are disclosing it. You're just making it hard to read.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: not so quickly.

It is undeniable that, as a candidate, it is very good to have a high reputation. I would say that a high reputation helps in making you be noticed, even "shine": if you can be seen in a large pool of developers, that's always a very good thing.

As an interviewer, however, you have to be careful. Sure, it is a good indicator, but I know plenty of good (not stellar, but good) people that have no Stack Exchange profile at all. And someone else that has a profile, but get to answer only a bunch of questions.

And on the other hand, I have personally interviewed a developer with a MUCH higher Stack Overflow reputation than mine. In the end, he was a no-hire. Why? He had a very high rep from answering (in a good way, I have to say) trivial questions, a lot of them. But he failed the first technical question about the software we make (recursion).

High rep is indication of a good sense of community, of great expertise in some area. Great expertise is very good for some jobs, but not something you (usually) value too much if you are looking for an all-around developer. It does not necessarily indicate that you are a good thinker, which is what I look for in a developer.

So, while a high rep may be a good indicator, the kind of questions asked and answered is much, much more important IMHO.

Comment: Good to point out that answering trivial questions can build a lot of rep. I think just looking at a number is far less meaningful than the quality of the work. Like many things, you've got to dig deeper than the face value to get at the true character of the thing.

Comment: Not just trivial questions. If I were to game the system, I would be making a lot of minor formatting edits....

Answer (score 7):

Rep is magical unicorn points (though as stated it does seem to open doors), however, the content of your account is not.

It will not help you in the interview but it can be useful on a CV for a couple of reasons.

Imagine it: you have a pile of 300 people and they all have the same experience and qualifications (not a rare scenario these days), how do you whittle those down to just 5?

SO and GitHub and other such profiles really help here and due to the "base" level of qualifications from post-uni potentials some employers have told me they will not hire without creds other than a degree.

It is starting to catch on for older, more senior, positions too where qualifications and experience are starting to no longer be a benchmark either.

As said by @TimPost ( [Is it legitimate to "buy" Stack Overflow reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270795/is-it-legitimate-to-buy-stack-overflow-reputation/270815#270815) ):

> Employers do look for participation on Stack Overflow now.

So yes, an SO account can help you get an interview, it will not help in the interview itself.

If your account proves you might be good on a help desk you might need to rethink about what questions you answer.

Comment: Does that imply that potential employers go from 300 to 5 by looking at those with github and stackoverflow? I don't want a lazy employer like that. That could work as a differentiator but not as "I'll only look at guys who spend their times on github and I don't care about those who spend their time on their own projects without sharing the code with the community".

Comment: @Bomboca What else are they supposed to look at? I mean they can't interview all 300 peple. So they have to find a way of picking potentials out of a huge stack, I mean this is extremely common and will happen in any high demand job you apply for.

Comment: What else? Definitely something else because that's not enough. That's why they invented HR to hire people. If you don't have time, that's okay but HR and recruitment, that's all they do. You might argue these people are not properly instructed on what to look for except a few keywords but that's another matter. I won't be creating open source projects just because someone says I should spend my days on it.

Comment: To finalise, I understand looking at your code or questions will allow me to understand how good or bad you are (assuming that rep is true - but that's another matter) but if I don't have such criteria available, I wouldn't dismiss a candidate. I'll have to go and look for more criteria possibilities to evaluate properly. Not looking at a CV just because someone doesn't post projects on github, is not just wrong. Such answers will wrongly influence employers to think that's the right thing to do and miss the opportunity to hire great people. I met some awesome devs who don't do any of that!

Comment: @Bomboca "open source projects just because someone says I should spend my days on it" If you were then you would be looking for the wrong job. This such stuff would be picked up in an interview. The stuff you love doing day in day out helps you get a job you love. If you have to apply that kind of effort to get a job then you are in the wrong industry. You should already have those projects cos you love programming, you should already be active in a programming community because that is where you like to be

Comment: @Bomboca If you wouldn't then that is your choice, some people do not like those who they cannot at least get some feel of before they enter an interview. Some CVs are so disproportionate to the person themselves that you cannot rely on how a CV is written or done for that. I have had it many times where the CV gave off an air of knowledge and prowess but the person was less than suitable frankly.

Comment: @Bomboca You may have some but I can say right now I have met many more bad ones by doing exactly that.

Comment: @Bomboca Poeple don't want good programmers, they want programmer who loves their job. A programmer who loves his/her job will already have these things normally.

Comment: your last point is not that linear but I get it. About the open source stuff: "This such stuff would be picked up in an interview". If you dismiss 295 out of 300, then you wouldn't have the opportunity to pick that stuff on an interview. I guess we don't totally disagree. I think you dismiss people too soon while you think I dismiss them too late in the process which ends up being a lot of work. Surely, but that's why recruitment (when properly done - which I don't remember seeing often by the way) is a full-time job. Cheers!

Comment: @Bomboca true, if I am honest the "5" is not actually set by me. It is set by others who say that...I would go for a higher number if I were allowed to. But it seems to be a really common number, especially for smaller businesses.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but there are limits.

Stack Overflow reputation points is a sign of passion for your profession. This is valuable in the same way as having a technical blog and/or github profile with open source activity. It is not likely to get you hired by itself, but it helps differentiate you from other candidates. Two scenarios where I see it helping are:

1. Entry level positions (where passion is one of the few leading indicators of future success)
2. Corporate/government IT developer positions (where finding passionate developers can be really hard)

Comment: An accomplished SO member is not going to be applying for an entry level position. In most instances, developing for a corporation/government would suck the soul out of a passionate developer. You are not considered a creator/maker, rather a necessary burden and are treated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely. Not only have I been asked about my SO profile and/or pointed it out without being explicitly asked, I have even received two separate requests for a job interview based on my profile (according to the introductory mail).

Even though my score isn't even that high, apparently being an active member here positively reflects upon me as a developer. Of course, I couldn't tell if and how many potential interviews I have been denied because of employers who think otherwise and thus decided not to invite me. Still, so far I've had good experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, at least, people *have* remarked about my Stack Overflow activity, but nobody cares about reputation points *per se*. The trick is that most of my answers have been in the [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) tag, a relatively small and self-contained community.

So what actually impressed people was my participation in that particular community. Moreover, since there's a manageable amount of activity in the tag, people actually remembered seeing me answer questions and liked some of my specific answers, which also helped.

So I would add that Stack Overflow is a good way to **augment your reputation in a niche topic**.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider interviewing people for a position by searching Stack Overflow for the keywords I am looking for and see who have the highest reputations for those categories as a way to quickly filter and find "experts".

I would still go through all the other interview hiring steps. It would just be a way to find specialized applicants.

Comment: Yes, but see for example *[A Terms of Service update restricting companies that scrape your profile information without your permission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa)*.

Comment: And *[How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/57537)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I didn't mention anything about scraping or hiring cheap labor to spam people. Also the jobs site that they mention in your link was shutdown in April 2022. If people want to be contacted from SO, they can put a link to their LinkedIn etc. in their profile

Answer (score 0):

**Nope**
Imho the 'reputation' score itself shouldn't matter much.
Although, activity and participation are probably good indicators.
The tone, quality/clarity of the user's posted content may be more useful for interviewers.

My concern about the 'reputation' score is newer members have much higher concurrency regarding answering a question and their questions more likely will be duplicates. In contrast, older members had more opportunities to earn reputation points via Q&A.

Bright intellect, genuine interest, and a helpful attitude are key here, not the scores.

Answer (score -7):

Of course, I always ask.  But unfortunately most of the time they don't have it or they have a real low rating due to only asking questions and not really anxious about building points.

Comment: You can earn reputation by asking questions, too. And there's nothing wrong with this from an employer's perspective. It shows that the person is self-motivated enough to try all means available to them to solve a problem. Plus, asking a good question is difficult. It draws together a lot of skills, including communication, research, and debugging. (Of course, a good balance of questions and answers is probably best.)

Comment: Yea, maybe you misunderstood what i was saying.  Where I would be more inclined to hire someone who has above 100k rating, over someone who has 1k rating, means a lot.  I wouldn't hire someone just because they have 1k rating, why should I?  On top of that, the person with the 100k rating, might take longer on my job b/c they're on here instead procrastinating.  Depends on the project relationship and what is expected.

Answer (score -11):

I think Stack Overflow reputation may show the ability to work on a helpdesk in some way, but it isn't generally an indication of good programming ability.

Remember that the purpose of Stack Overflow is to be a big global online helpdesk for technical problems, and not a "best coding practice" site.

I would like to know that if I'm paying developers, they would be possibly spending time on Stack Overflow to find solutions to problems that come up, not solving them for others on paid time. Of course there may be an occasional submission of an answer, especially if they looked up a problem, found a question and no suitable answer, then solved it themselves.

There are also other factors as to why they have a high reputation. If they have been here a long time, for example. If they have been lucky. Or they cheated the system and got away with it.

Comment: That: *`Remember that the purpose of StackOverflow is to be a big global online helpdesk for technical problems`* is **wrong**! I think SO has become a help desk over the last year or two caused by summer of love and other idiotic events but that's certainly was **not** the original purpose or intention...

Comment: Well a combination of a knowledge base and helpdesk. But unlike several other places with a "contact us" link that doesn't give you any contact details because they want you to search FAQs first, this site makes it easier to ask the questions first, get shot later.

Answer (score -14):

If I was interviewing a developer and found out they had a really high rep on SO, I would equate that with a tendency to monitor SO, which can reduce productivity. In other words, time that they're goofing off when they should be working.

Sure, lots of people answer questions on SO in their free time, but it inevitably spills over into their work time. Let's say the person is working, tries to trouble shoot a problem by searching google, lands on SO, and sees a notification - That notification leads to responding to a comment, checking where points came from, aka, a time suck.

SO also tries to task people who have higher reps with moderation duties, this sucks even more time out of a developer's billable hours.

IMHO, high SO rep would reflect negatively on a job candidate.

Comment: What if they have high rep due to two answers which have upvotes of 100+?

Comment: Seriously? Have you actually ever interviewed anyone? You think participating in a community focused about solving programming problems affects a programmer _negatively_ ?!?

Comment: Ha, I knew this would be an unpopular answer. People don't want to hear it. But it's what I honestly believe.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I do think it affects them negatively. I want hired developers to give me every minute of their billable hour. Not monitor SO.

Comment: It's not about being an unpopular answer - it's a very clear indication that you haven't actually interviewed a lot though. As someone who interviews I'd kill for more candidates who are interested enough in their profession to spend time thinking about it in their free time. Stack Overflow participation and high rep also usually indicates problem solving abilities (in contrast to programming ability).

Comment: I mean take this answer for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1643247/383478 I know quite a few users who have high rep solely from answering only a few questions, if you base "slacker" on rep then you could take quite a few people who don't let SO spill over out of the equation. Also sicne you use SO are you not also a slacker the same?

Comment: Every minute of their billable time? Micro manage much? I couldn't care less what my team is doing as long as they're getting the job done - if they work 5 hours and surf twitter 4.5 hours out of that and still manage to produce more reliable maintainable high quality working software in the remaining 30 minutes than most developers out there would in 8 hours - I'd hire them right away.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think side projects are a better way to show passion for coding.

Comment: @Sammaye You can tell from that answer that that person has answered many questions on SO just by the number of badges they have.

Comment: @inorganik side projects are also important and no doubt that a good GitHub profile leaves a good mark - but having impressive answers that demonstrate domain knowledge in Stack Overflow is also a strong indication of a passionate individual who cares about programming. We need _more_ of those and I certainly wouldn't count it _against_ anyone. Then again - I don't care what developers do as long as their throughput is good and you care about what they do in every minute of their time. Be sure not to buy a coffee maker so they won't spend time they could be coding making coffee -_-

Comment: I had 80% of my badges before I started answering questions, when I asked only questions, badges is not a reliable measurement

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you make some good points.

Comment: On a side note, are you at your workplace currently? :) Apart from that, I think most of the users with really ridiculously high reps work in really good companies. Just take a glance through the [first page of top users](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) and you'll see companies like Google, Microsoft, Stack Exchange employees having hundreds of thousands of rep. And I am sure they contribute greatly to these companies.

Comment: I'd also like to add that being active in SO definitely gives me an edge when I start leaning a new technology, people are much friendlier in chat rooms and are much more willing to help me when I'm stuck - I also know how to navigate the system and find answers to my problems better.

Comment: Though having high rep also seems to make some people forget that SO is not your research consultant :\, so it has its down sides when you move to new tech as well but that would come out in personality tests within an interview

Comment: tl;dr the comments. You can't honestly except any worker to be 100% full time dedicated to working during work. We'd go insane. SO provides the means to "slack off" at work while staying productive. If you drive your developers that hard, they're liable to leave you.

Comment: @inorganik - There's a difference between knowledge workers and material workers...a single missed minute in a factory setup would see production decline and a real impact.  That isn't true in a knowledge based industry where what your employee knows is their greatest contribution.  I've been with a software company that set out 6 productive hours per employee per day, the other 2-3 were for networking and learning/keeping up to date on their respective fields (stack included).  Running a company as you suggest here would quickly result in braindrain as your brightest employees head else where

Comment: I'm with Joel: they are *underemployed*: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/20407/will-high-reputation-in-stack-overflow-help-to-get-a-good-job#comment31380_20491. I would also say that you don't have to "monitor" Stack Overflow to get high rep: one person takes a cigarette break, I take a SO break.

Comment: *"In other words, time that they're goofing off when they should be working."* This is the part where your thinking goes off the rails. You cannot draw that conclusion from the premises. You don't know that they are answering questions on Stack Overflow when they "should be working". Maybe they never get on the site at work; maybe they do all of their posting at home. That would be a good sign, that they think about programming problems and sharpen their skills on their own time, not just at work. As an employer, that would be highly desirable. Or maybe they built up rep while unemployed.

Comment: I think it's a good answer - it'd be unpopular on SO, because... well, we're here, so we think otherwise. It's good to remind everyone here that the person hiring you doesn't necessarily hold that same opinion. That's a two edged sword though - I probably wouldn't be a 'good fit' at a company that worked like that, so perhaps SO points would help me avoid a job I wouldn't get on with...

Comment: It might be true that it would take time out of their day (after all, I'm posting on SO right now instead of working), but overall it makes him/her a better developer. It's inevitable not to learn anything while browsing / asking / answering on SO, so all-in-all, I think the time "wasted" on SO is still more productive than a person who just does their job all day and doesn't learn new stuff.

Comment: Why down vote this answer? If this person is really hiring people his answer is absolutely valid, he's not lying, and this is something I would like to know in advance before going to an interview. I don't agree with him but that's another story, the vote is not related to his criteria to hire people.

Comment: Feeling like I should take back this answer bc I was just contacted by an employer bc of all my answers on a certain topic on stack.

Comment: I feel the same, people downvote this question must never tried to manage people before, lol.  ++1 -- Perfect answer.  Just make sure when you hire someone with a high rating, make sure you have a delivery time defined!