# Print as pdf / document the status of our profile in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Could we possibly have this feature? Where Stack Overflow will give us the summary of our profile, which would be legitimate.

Like including "Reputation", "gold / silver / bronze medals" and "people reached count", "number of questions", "answers" and "top tags" and "number of bounties won", and some features customizable to be in the report (leaderboard ranking / or any other).

It would be awesome if Stack Overflow could generate a report. So that this can be used to produce to industry, claiming our support in Stack Overflow.

Comment: But isn't that encouraging to us , having a offical status page by stackoverflow !!!!!!

Comment: If you want to brag / display your Stack Overflow profile somewhere you can use your [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/13431819.png), you'll find a nice shareable HTML representation of it in your [settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13431819/krishna-acharya/flair)

Comment: just flair wouldn't suffice to brag :) @AbdulAzizBarkat, An official certificate would be such a honor

Comment: I feel like you're just trying to fish for certificates. Stack Overflow isn't primarily a programming challenge site you can bring to interviews to show off -- it's a Q&A site where reputation just happened to be picked up as a metric for some employers. Even the help center says reputation isn't an accurate metric, and that the only thing it tries to estimate is trust to grant expanded privileges. "would be such a honor" - would it? If everyone gets one automatically, that undermines the value of a certificate. Just link to your profile and move on. That system already exists

Comment: Yes i fish for the certificate . Okay I'll manage with the link .

Comment: Somewhat related - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271008/would-you-consider-stack-overflow-reputation-valuable-at-interviews - I'm in "newer seen SO rep used in resumes/never asked for one/never got asked about" camp...

Comment: Wasn't there a recent duplicate?

Comment: Of this question ? I deleted that post

Comment: Related: *[Printing out Stack Overflow/Exchange Q&As including comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/printing-out-stack-overflow-exchange-qas-including-comments)*

Comment: What do you mean by *"...produce to industry, claiming our support in Stack Overflow."*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Thank youu Peter for being the first person to consider my pov and trying to understand my question . By this i mean we can have a legit official way of showing our contribution in SO, support in terms of answers questions bounties and the like , it wouldn't actually be a certificate , it will be like our profile in a nice official format which would specify our contribution on stack overflow, based on which people have opinion about the persons convincing capabilities, his area of interests by seeing the famous tags his work is on and the like .

Comment: Sooo i propose to have a official doc/pdf format of our SO profile which speaks about our contribution . Not necessarily something to brag about. Just the profile and every details in a official manner, which would be uniform throughout

Comment: “Of this question ? I deleted that post” - You should avoid doing that. You really should avoid asking a question then deleting it because you didn’t like the reception it received.

Comment: @SecurityHound I'll undelete it no worries

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature, nor is it planned.

However, there are some alternatives and to summarize the various comments:

- You can send a link to your SO account.
- You can embed the flair in your website/blog/email.
- You can use CRTL + P to print/save as PDF your profile page.