# How can I make the best out of contributing to SO?

Tags: discussion, reputation

From childhood, I've been using this site for discovering a lot of interesting and informative questions and answers about programming. Nevertheless, I've been actively using this site for months now and I feel addicted.

I feel addicted to reading a *lot* of answers here. I've simply exhausted my favorite tags by reading the most voted list. I see a new question and for answering it I spend hours of research and come into conclusion. And I've been active here since one month only.

As I'm a college undergrad, sometimes I worry what does the 'reputation' really mean for StackOverflow and the world outside it. If I go on and on contributing, answering and voting questions and answers, how can I can make a benefit out of it?

I'd love to read answers from users with years of experience and still feel love for StackOverflow.

Comment: `If I go on and on contributing, answering and voting questions and answers, how can I can make a benefit out of it?` --> StackOverflow Career

Comment: "From childhood"? I find that hard to believe. Stack Overflow has only been around for shy of 7 years. You would have to be a very young teenager now at your oldest to have used the site since childhood.

Comment: I'm 19, I call 16 my childhood. :)

Comment: Opinion based question on meta? Say it ain't so!

Comment: What does "discussion" mean to you people? People presenting their own facts? No, facts mixed with opinions. Put on hold my foot.

Comment: [Professional benefits of building reputation on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254257/professional-benefits-of-building-reputation-on-so?rq=1) (although that doesn't mention moderation or working for [se] itself, which are also options worth considering if you're really passionate about the site).

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271008/would-you-consider-stack-overflow-reputation-valuable-at-interviews

Comment: Embrace you inner hate - get on Lounge C++

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apart from the possibility of reputation perhaps helping land a job one day, and awesome [swag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261505/is-it-true-that-if-someone-reaches-200k-reputation-he-she-gets-a-painting-with-a/), there aren't *that* many material benefits.

The undertaking of building a (hopefully, somewhat) useful resource  of knowledge for the world should be fulfilling in itself to some degree. Otherwise being active on SO/SE may not be very satisfying in the long run.

While answering questions on SO teaches you a *lot* - there are plenty of things I know only because I did research for a SO answer! - it may not be an ideal only activity if you're  in the early stages of a career and looking to shape useful professional skills.

It *could* be that part the time you can invest might be better spent doing something else, like working on an Open Source project or learning a new programming language.

You'll be sticking around Stack Overflow anyway because <strike>IT HAS YOU HOOKED</strike> you love it!

Comment: +1 for this `there are plenty of things I know only because I did research for a SO answer!`

Answer (score 11):

> If I go on and on contributing [...] how can I can make a benefit out of it?

You can work on your experience, which will help you in a professional way:

- Improve your English by reading a lot and practicing writing a lot.
- Learn to get a complete problem description out of someone by asking the right questions.
- Work on your troubleshooting skills by mentally debugging code someone posted, and if that doesn't work, paste it in your IDE and debug it from your own machine.
- Learn about new possibilities of libraries and frameworks, or even about new tools or languages altogether.

> What does the 'reputation' really mean for [the world outside Stack Overflow]?

It doesn't have to mean much. I sometimes encounter people on the site who are recognized outside of SO, yet they have a measly three- or four-digit reputation here after years of participating. Their answers and comments are always insightful, yet hardly ever get upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it is difficult to define "best", however, the following quote by Jeff Atwood [here](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/) gives me the satisfaction about contributing to this site:

> when we're learning from each other, *everyone* wins

Comment: ... unless you learn all the wrong things. Making sure people are in the best possible situation to really win in a good way is a day job for moderators and reviewers.